# Yii: Access CActiveForm.htmlOptions from controller when form is submitted to change css visibility

Tags: php, yii

I have a CActiveForm which when submitted should make a second CActiveForm become visible. I know how to change the htmlOptions of the form when its created but not how to access it via the controller.

My View with two forms. The second form has visibility:hidden

```
<div class="form">
            <?php
            $numberForm = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                'id' => 'addnumber-form',
                'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
                'clientOptions' => array(
                    'validateOnSubmit' => true,
                ),
                    ));
            ?>

            <p class="note"><?php echo UserModule::t('Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.'); ?></p>
            <?php echo $numberForm->errorSummary($numberModel); ?>

            <div class="row">
                <?php echo $numberForm->labelEx($numberModel, 'number'); ?>
                <?php echo $numberForm->textField($numberModel, 'number'); ?>
                <?php echo $numberForm->error($numberModel, 'number'); ?>

                <?php
                echo CHtml::submitButton(UserModule::t("Verify"), array(
                    "class" => "btn btn-success"
                ));
                ?>

            </div>

            <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

            <?php
            $verifyForm = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                    'id' => 'verify-form',
                    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
                    'clientOptions' => array(
                        'validateOnSubmit' => true,
                    ),
                    'htmlOptions' => array("style"=>"visibility: hidden"),
                ));
            ?>

            <?php echo $verifyForm->errorSummary($verifyModel); ?>

            <p>A authorisation code has been sent to your phone. Please enter it below. If you don't receive a text message make sure you entered your number correctly and try again</p>

            <div class="row">
                <?php echo $verifyForm->labelEx($verifyModel, 'authcodeUser'); ?>
                <?php echo $verifyForm->textField($verifyModel, 'authcodeUser'); ?>
                <?php echo $verifyForm->error($verifyModel, 'authcodeUser'); ?>

                <?php
                echo CHtml::submitButton(UserModule::t("Confirm"), array(
                    "class" => "btn btn-success"
                ));
                ?>

                <?php
                    foreach(Yii::app()->user->getFlashes() as $key => $message) {
                        echo '<div class="flash-' . $key . '">' . $message . "</div>\n";
                    }
                ?>

            </div>

            <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>


        </div><!-- form -->
```

My controller for these forms

```
public function actionAddnumber(){
    $numberModel = new UserAddNumber;
    $verifyModel = new UserVerifyNumber;
    if (Yii::app()->user->id) {

        // ajax validator
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='addnumber-form')
        {
            echo UActiveForm::validate($numberModel);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }

        if(isset($_POST['UserAddNumber'])) {
                $numberModel->attributes=$_POST['UserAddNumber'];
                if($numberModel->validate()) {
                    $profile = Profile::model()->findByAttributes(array('user_id'=>Yii::app()->user->id));
                    $profile->mobileNo = $numberModel->number;
                    $profile->save();

                    //MAKE $verifyForm visibility to visible uring htmlOptions

                    Yii::app()->session['authcode'] = '4444';
                }
        }

        if(isset($_POST['UserVerifyNumber'])) {
                $verifyModel->attributes=$_POST['UserVerifyNumber'];
                if($verifyModel->validate()) {
                    $profile = Profile::model()->findByAttributes(array('user_id'=>Yii::app()->user->id));
                    $profile->mobileNoVerified = True;
                    $profile->save();
                    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('profileMessage',UserModule::t("Your mobile number has been verified"));
                    $this->redirect(array("profile"));

                }
        }

    }
    $this->render('addnumber', array('numberModel'=>$numberModel, 'verifyModel' => $verifyModel));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you could just create a new variable for whether or not to show the second form and then pass it to the view. Here is your controller:

```
public function actionAddnumber(){
    $numberModel = new UserAddNumber;
    $verifyModel = new UserVerifyNumber;
    $formVisibility = "hidden";

    if (Yii::app()->user->id) {

        // ajax validator
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='addnumber-form')
        {
            echo UActiveForm::validate($numberModel);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }

        if(isset($_POST['UserAddNumber'])) {
                $numberModel->attributes=$_POST['UserAddNumber'];
                if($numberModel->validate()) {
                    $profile = Profile::model()->findByAttributes(array('user_id'=>Yii::app()->user->id));
                    $profile->mobileNo = $numberModel->number;
                    $profile->save();

                    //MAKE $verifyForm visibility to visible uring htmlOptions
                    $formVisibility = "visible";


                    Yii::app()->session['authcode'] = '4444';
                }
        }

        if(isset($_POST['UserVerifyNumber'])) {
                $verifyModel->attributes=$_POST['UserVerifyNumber'];
                if($verifyModel->validate()) {
                    $profile = Profile::model()->findByAttributes(array('user_id'=>Yii::app()->user->id));
                    $profile->mobileNoVerified = True;
                    $profile->save();
                    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('profileMessage',UserModule::t("Your mobile number has been verified"));
                    $this->redirect(array("profile"));

                }
        }

    }
    $this->render('addnumber', array('numberModel'=>$numberModel, 'verifyModel' => $verifyModel, 'formVisibility' => $formVisibility));
}
```

And here is the first part of your second form:

```
<?php
            $verifyForm = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                    'id' => 'verify-form',
                    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
                    'clientOptions' => array(
                        'validateOnSubmit' => true,
                    ),
                    'htmlOptions' => array("style"=>"visibility: ".$formVisibility),
                ));
            ?>
```

[edit] To make sure I am answering your question, I should add that I've never seen any way of changing the htmlOptions from the controller directly. That's why I proposed this solution instead.